# multiple values to another activity only retrieving last value

Tags: android

I'm scratching my head over this one. Basically what I am trying to do is I am trying to pass multiple values to the next activity, however when receiving the values in the next value, only the last one comes through.

In Activity A I have this

```
public void aberdeen1(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, details.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString(storename, "storenamevalue");
        extras.putString(address1, "streetaddress");
        extras.putString(address2, "streetaddress2");
        extras.putString(town, "City");
        extras.putString(postcode, "AB12 3CD");         
        extras.putString(telnumber, "01234 567890");
        extras.putString(faxnumber, "01234 567899");
        i.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

In Activity B I have this

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String storename = extras.getString(StoreListA.storename);
storename1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.storename);
storename1.setText(storename);

String address1 = extras.getString(StoreListA.address1);
address01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address1);
address01.setText(address1);

String address2 = extras.getString(StoreListA.address2);
address02 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address2);

String town = extras.getString(StoreListA.town);
town1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.town);

String postcode = extras.getString(StoreListA.postcode);
postcode1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postcode); 

String telnumber = extras.getString(StoreListA.telnumber);
telnumber1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telnumber);

String faxnumber = extras.getString(StoreListA.faxnumber);
faxnumber1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faxnumber);

}
```

all that shows for each textview is the fax number. need some help, I have tried other methods but this seemed to be the best way of doing it.

Comment: are you sure your keys are all unique?

Comment: sounds like a pretty dumb question I know, but how would I go about checking the keys? I have seen that mentioned before when I have searched.

Comment: so the keys are your StoreListA.storename etc, can you post those in the OP?

Comment: they are yes. I have put them in the OP, I have only put two in there as I want to make sure I have the first two working before going any further with the other textviews. It is only StoreListA.storename and StoreListA.address1 I have got to so far

Comment: Have you tried the Intent.putExtra(), Intent.getStringExtra() methods instead? It's a long shot, but, ya know, I would expect the code you have to work.

Comment: @panini after double checking, the keys weren't unique, after a difficult day at work then coming home to that. It wasn't good, after having a cup of coffee this morning, I changed them and we are all good

Comment: good to hear! might want to add that as an answer and accept it to get your acceptance rating up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after double checking, the keys weren't unique, after a difficult day at work then coming home to that. It wasn't good, after having a cup of coffee this morning, I changed them and we are all good.

Answer (score 1):

//Store Class

```
public static class Store implements Serializable{
        String storeName;
        String address1;
        String address2;
        String town;
        String postCode;
        String telNumber;
        String faxNumber;

        Store(String storeName, 
              String address1, 
              String address2, 
              String town, 
              String postCode, String telNumber, String faxNumber){

            this.storeName = storeName;
            this.address1 = address1;
            this.address2 = address2;
            this.town = town;
            this.postCode = postCode;
            this.telNumber = telNumber;
            this.faxNumber = faxNumber;
        }
    }

    public void aberdeen1(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, details.class);
        i.putExtra("store", new Store("storenamevalue",
                                       "streetaddress",
                                       "streetaddress2",
                                       "City",
                                       "AB12 3CD",
                                       "01234 567890","01234 567899"));
        startActivity(i);
    }

//In Another Activity (Details).

//Whichever Activity you are coming from.

Activivty.Store store = (Activity.Store)getIntent()
                         .getExtras()
                         .getSerializable("store");
```

For more information on passing objects between Activities - [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use your constants in both activities not only the one you are sending the data to. Also remember the key is first parameter in the putString call and the value is the second. It's hard to tell from your code which is the key and which is the value.

Ex:

`extras.putString(StoreListA.storename, "This is the value for the name");`